# Aspectj woven both annotated methodA and methodB calling methodA

Tags: aop, aspectj

for example:I want to implement an AOP retry function

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(retryed)")
public void retry(Retry retryed) {}

@Around("retry(retryed)")
public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Retry retryed) throws Throwable {
    Object result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        result = pjp.proceed();
    }
    return result;
}



@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    unAnnotatedMethodC();
}
private void unAnnotatedMethodC() {
    System.out.println("unAnnotatedMethodC");
    unAnnotatedMethodB();
}
private void unAnnotatedMethodB() {
    System.out.println("unAnnotatedMethodB");
    annotatedMethodA();
}
@Retry
private void annotatedMethodA() {
    System.out.println("annotatedMethodA");
}
```

output:

```
unAnnotatedMethodC
unAnnotatedMethodB
annotatedMethodA
annotatedMethodA
annotatedMethodA
annotatedMethodA
```

[look the .class file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3YtV.png)

it has woven twice,its not i hope,i want output like this

```
unAnnotatedMethodC
unAnnotatedMethodB
annotatedMethodA
annotatedMethodA
```

How can I avoid this problem？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pointcut expression matches both `execution` and `call` type pointcuts, that's why you get double matches. `execution` type pointcuts match the location of the method's bytecode, while `call` type pointcuts will match the bytecode of the call sites of code invoking those methods. You'll need to restrict your code to `execution` type pointcuts to avoid invoking the around advice twice:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(retryed) && execution(* *(..))")
```

See [call vs execution](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html#call-vs-execution) in the AspectJ programming guide for further reference.